# Problemas con IP Works SSL v9 SMTP

Tags: delphi

Estoy trabajando sobre RAD Studio XE7 y usando IP Works SSL v9 para montar un servicio que me permitirá enviar un correo por smtp 465. Después  de aceptar el token y cuando el sistema intenta realizar la conexión me da esta excepción:

> Excepción: 161: SMTP protocol error. Invalid SASL XOAUTH2 credentials.
>   {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}.

Tengo el servicio de descargar los correo montado en ese mismo sistema y funciona de maravilla, incluso este código funcionaba hace unos 2 meses pero ahora me muestra esta excepción.

gracias de antemano

Comment: Desconozco si IPWorks implementa OAuth2. Si lo soporta, te servirá saber que el error está relacionado con el token de acceso de OAuth2.